# Providing meaningful error messages to Unity3d WWW.error from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unity-game-engine

I am learning how to post data to a web server from Unity3d as a first step towards creating a leaderboard for my game. Right now I have a very simple script in Unity that posts a name and score to my server. The PostScoreURL maps to a create action in Rails (when sent as a POST). It is very simple but works on a basic level.

Unity has a WWW class that I am using to POST to the server.  This class has an error property but it is always coming up as 500 Internal Server Error; it has this error if the user is successfully created or if the user is not created due to a validation problem. I would like to add to my Rails app so that I can send more meaningful error messages back to Unity so that the user will know what is going on.  For example, if they try to create a user that already exists, they should be notified that they need to use a different name.

Here is my code:
The Unity script:

```
string PostScoreURL = "http://localhost:3000/users";
string name = "Melanie";
int score = 8732;
WWW www;
bool requestSent = false;

void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100),"Post Score"))
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("user[name]", name);
        form.AddField("user[score]", score);

        www = new WWW(PostScoreURL,form);
        requestSent = true;
    }

    if(requestSent && www.isDone)
    {
        print (www.error);
        requestSent = false;
    }
}
```

From the Rails app:
user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :score
    validates_presence_of :name, :score
    validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

Here is my create action:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.save
end
```

I would like to send back relevant error messages to Unity.  For example: Missing Username, Missing Score, Username taken.

Comment: from which devise are you running the unity app?

Comment: I've just been running it from the Unity editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't consider your *business rule errors* as *connection errors*, that is, those errors should be treated in the server side, returning to the client a "successful" response with an internal error code, defined by you.

I don't know RoR, it probably let you define error codes in the response, but in my case (that don't use RoR) we created a response class with error codes that is serialized and returned to the client. After that, WWW class calls a parser that will verify the error codes. Also, WWW watches for connection errors on WWW.error.

Comment: Yes you are right; the business rule errors would not show up in WWW.error which is used for connection errors.  Thank you for explaining that because I had it mixed up.  What I am doing now is sending messages back regarding success or errors in the WWW.text property.